# React State show as NaN

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, react-props

I am trying to setState from previous Props using, now, the deprecated componentWillReceiveProps like below

```
componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
  this.setState({
    temp: Math.round(((props.weather.temp-273.15)*1.8)+32)
  })
console.log(this.state)
}
```

The problem I am facing is when I do this, when the app updates, the state is **NaN** for 1 second before becoming the correct number.

I tried using componentWillMount(){} instead, but not only is that not a good lifecycle to use for setting state, the previous props *are not available during this time*

How can I prevent this NaN from appearing in the rendered DOM and only show the state?

**EDIT**

You are all correct. I was more concerned with whether there should be a lifecycle or React specific handler to resolve this kinda issue. I guess it's true that React is mostly comprised of plain ol' javascript.

Comment: Thank you @Yoav. My main concern is this, though.. Is this normal behavior? Is there not a lifeCycle method that would allow for the prop to come over as value immediately aside from componentWillMount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render the element only if it has value:

```
{ this.state.temp && <div>{this.state.temp}</div>}
```

This will not allow to render `NaN`.

---

You may know `Boolean(NaN)` returns false. So, the above expression will return false if the value is currently `NaN` and will not process further.

Answer (score 1):

My first assumption is that on one round of your component updating the weather prop is incorrect.

I would wrap the setState in a check to make sure the prop is a valid number before attempting to do the maths:

```
if(parseInt(props.weather.temp)){
    this.setState({
        temp: Math.round(((props.weather.temp-273.15)*1.8)+32)
    })
}
```

Console out the value and see what is coming through during the time it's NaN... Other than that without more code it's hard to help :)

Comment: I should note that this means it will retain the original value if the newest is incorrect. Whether this is what you want or not is not for me to know :P

Answer (score 1):

you can surround everything with an `if (props.weather && !isNaN(props.weather.temp))` so the state will only update once it receives a proper value

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem today, and I have the opposite experience to the answer.
In my experience:

```
{this.state.temp && <div>{this.state.temp}</div>}
```

If `this.state.temp` is not equal to `true`, this sentence will return `this.state.temp`.
Luckily, when it is `null`, `undefined`, `false`, or `''`, it will be rendered nothing on Web.
However, when it is `0` or `NaN`, `0` or `NaN` will be rendered on the screen.

Check the link below to get more explanations and solutions:

[How to make conditionally rendering safer](https://koprowski.it/2020/conditional-rendering-react-native-text-crash/)